# How do I make my custom config section behave like a collection?

Tags: c#, custom-configuration

How would I need to write my custom `ConfigurationSection` so that it is both a section handler and a configuration element collection?

Normally, you have one class that inherits from `ConfigurationSection`, which then has a property that is of a type that inherits from `ConfigurationElementCollection`, which then returns elements of a collection of a type that inherits from `ConfigurationElement`.  To configure that, you would then need XML that looks something like this:

```
<customSection>
  <collection>
    <element name="A" />
    <element name="B" />
    <element name="C" />
  </collection>
</customSection>
```

I want to cut out the `<collection>` node, and just have:

```
<customSection>
  <element name="A" />
  <element name="B" />
  <element name="C" />
<customSection>
```

Comment: Could you please consider changing the title of your question to be more specific? I suggest something like "How do I make my custom config section behave like a collection?" or something along those lines. This would automatically remove the "C#" from the question title which is unnecessary because you already tagged the question with it.

Comment: When you ask the actual question, you will soon realize that it's quite possible that someone has asked it already. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379110/custom-config-section-containing-collection) could be a duplicate of your question, for example.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I assume that the `collection` is a property of your custom `ConfigurationSection` class.

You can decorate this property with the following attributes:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MyElementCollection), AddItemName = "element")]
```

A full implementation for your example could look like this:

```
public class MyCustomSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MyElementCollection), AddItemName = "element")]
    public MyElementCollection Elements
    {
        get { return (MyElementCollection)this[""]; }
    }
}

public class MyElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection, IEnumerable<MyElement>
{
    private readonly List<MyElement> elements;

    public MyElementCollection()
    {
        this.elements = new List<MyElement>();
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        var element = new MyElement();
        this.elements.Add(element);
        return element;
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((MyElement)element).Name;
    }

    public new IEnumerator<MyElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.elements.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class MyElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)this["name"]; }
    }
}
```

Now you can access your settings like this:

```
var config = (MyCustomSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customSection");

foreach (MyElement el in config.Elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(el.Name);
}
```

This will allow the following configuration section:

```
<customSection>
    <element name="A" />
    <element name="B" />
    <element name="C" />
<customSection>
```

Comment: You have three classes in your example.  I know that's the way Microsoft shows us how to do it...but that means your XML will have three levels: the section, the collection, the elements in the collection.  I want to do it with two: the section, the elements in section (as if the section were also a colelction).

Comment: @theBoringCoder You indeed have still three levels in your classes, but this example uses exactly the example that you wanted. The `MyElementCollection` class does not translate to an xml element.

Comment: @theBoringCoder Wow, that's some delayed response :)